# Is there a word for wanting something more after losing it?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is there a word that somewhat resembles wanting something more after losing [possession of] it?

By something it can be for example:

- a person (family relative, close friend, relation partner) that is lost for example by being disowned, dying, departing/leaving;
- an object that is lost, taken away, sold;
- a university or work position.

Some long phrases could be:

- [Realize the importance of something after losing it.](https://www.quora.com/Why-we-always-realize-the-importance-of-something-after-losing-it)
- [Overvalue what we no longer have.](https://www.spencergreenberg.com/2013/10/why-we-overvalue-the-things-we-lose-the-psychology-of-loss/)
- [Not knowing what you have until it's gone.](https://www.elitedaily.com/life/you-dont-know-what-you-have-til-its-gone)
- [Losing something you want.](https://modernmrsdarcy.com/lose-something-you-want/)
- [Realise someone’s worth only after we’ve lost them.](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/we-realise-someones-worth-after-weve-lost-them/)

Comment: That would be [*Absence makes the heart grow fonder*.](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/absence-makes-the-heart-grow-fonder.html) Or as Joni Mitchell sings in "Big Yellow Taxi", [*You don't know what you've got 'till it's gone.*](https://jonimitchell.com/music/song.cfm?id=13)

Comment: From Google Dictionary: Yearn - have an intense feeling of longing for something, typically something that one has lost or been separated from.

Answer (score 2):

There is a super obscure english word, desiderium, that is defined as having feelings for something that we no longer have, and wish very much that we did.

No one actually uses it in conversation and it's not exactly "wanting something more now that you can't have it.

It's best to describe that feeling with multiple words.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, and this fact keeps our poets busy.

A word that might be helpful to you is "deprived", in that one might *feel deprived* of something one had that one lost.  Also, we have the word "bereft", technically from the word "bereave", meaning to suffer the loss of a loved one.  To be bereft is to be suffering for want of something or someone.

You may also be looking for the word "nostalgia", which refers to the feeling of wistful longing for things of the past.  There's a general understanding that nostalgia makes one view the past "through rose-colored glasses" (an idiom that means to regard things as better than they are or were.)